# Unknown table engine 'InnoDB' error

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I start my mysql it gives the following error on the log file. My default engine is MyIsam and I am using Innodb for a set of DB s only.

```
120604 12:24:49 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/mysql1.pid1 ended
120604 12:24:58 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
120604 12:24:58 [ERROR] InnoDB: syntax error in innodb_data_file_path
120604 12:24:58 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120604 12:24:58 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
120604 12:24:58 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
120604 12:24:58 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.35-community-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock1'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

the below is InnoDB table and it gives the Unknown table engine 'InnoDB' error ?

```
mysql (mydb) > show create table sitemap;
ERROR 1286 (42000): Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'
```

My my.cnf is:

```
[mysqld]
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock1
port = <port>
bind-address = <ip>
pid-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql1.pid1
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
user = mysql
log-error = /var/lib/mysql/err.log
log-bin=Master-mysql-bin
server-id       = 1
ft_min_word_len = 2
skip-show-database
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:194.19922M:autoextend
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not see this error before, but I can that from the error log:

```
120604 12:24:58 [ERROR] InnoDB: syntax error in innodb_data_file_path
120604 12:24:58 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120604 12:24:58 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

It should be clear that you have a problem in your configuration specifically in `innodb_data_file_path` value. You can try to comment it and restart mysql. If it was successful, you can try to find a proper value for this option.

Answer (score 0):

In your my.cnf I see the following:

```
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:194.19922M:autoextend
```

You have a decimal point in the number : 194.19922

Please round it to 194 and change it to

```
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:194M:autoextend
```

and restart mysql